# D3.js Flipping text at the bottom half of a donut (arcs)

Tags: javascript, regex, d3.js

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs.html). I made it to the last part, but with my data, the code doesn't work (I will explain later).

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydx9y9sx/) of the code so far. I have commented the part that flips the text so that it works.

```
if (d.endAngle > 90 * Math.PI/180) {
   var startLoc     = /M(.*?)A/,        
   middleLoc    = /A(.*?)0 0 1/,
   endLoc       = /0 0 1 (.*?)$/;
   var newStart = endLoc.exec( newArc )[1];
   var newEnd = startLoc.exec( newArc )[1];
   var middleSec = middleLoc.exec( newArc )[1];
   newArc = "M" + newStart + "A" + middleSec + "0 0 0 " + newEnd;
}
```

So far, I have not understood what the regex are all about (even before this part, like `var firstArcSection = /(^.+?)L/;`). The only factor should be the angle, and then we should just rotate the text 180 degrees and place it around the arc again facing the right way.

Here's the data:

```
var donutData = [
        {name: "firstArc", value: 16},
        {name: "secondArc", value: 9},
        {name: "thirdArc",  value: 2},
        {name: "fourthArc", value: 62},
        {name: "fifthArc", value: 23},
        {name: "sixthArc", value: 21}
];
```

Here's my issue: the code above works in some configurations, if I change the value of "thirdArc" to 20 for instance, or if I change other values. Some cases work, some don't (`endLoc.exec( newArc )[1];` becomes undefined).

I have also seen a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992446/i-want-to-flip-the-text-on-the-bottom-half-in-donut-chart-using-d3-js), but I have no idea what causes TEXT to be flipped at the bottom in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/xrro96xg/1/), as there is nothing about angle or start and end points.

My questions are how do I flip the texts at the bottom half of the first [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydx9y9sx/), and what are the regex for?

Comment: We have just recently discussed this very same example. The error happens when specifying arcs of more than 180 degrees. Have a look at [*"Error when providing svg v1 path parameter d"*](/q/40370212) for more insights. It might even be a true duplicate of that question, but I cannot mark it as such because that question has not yet an accepted answer.